# How to host mvc5 project with Database on Godaddy server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I have 3 projects (MVC5 Web, Database and DB First EF) in one solution. I can host properly MVC5 simple app (not including database) in Godaddy server. I'm able to create DB in Godaddy server too (i.e. by creating scripts in local SQL Server MS in my pc and pasing in the Godaddy SQL Server. Its working fine.) and got Connection string. Now my question is, 
1- Should I host my "DB First EF" ? If yes then how ? 
2- Suppose I want to change my DB, how to modify my edmx file in server? (Like we do in Visual Studio When ever we modify any DB object, We can change our edmx manually.)
Any suggestion would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1;- yes, 2 when you deploy your solution in your folder bin you'll have the dll's to references the data access layer, if you need to update your EF, update it first locally with your VS, and then deploy again your solution, or just update the dll for data access layer in the bin folder

Comment: Ah! Thank u very much. I got it. A small doubt, bin folder is always excluded from project. Should I include it before deploy or ?